# Bash script to delete backup files within a given directory & calling a calling that script in another method?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a test harness called "test.sh" that will create 24 backup files in a directory called "D1" with extensions .txt~, .bak, and 12 files that start with #. In this test harness I have to call another method called "clean.sh" that will delete all the files in the given directory (in this case D1).

This is my test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Create new directory called D1
mkdir D1

#cd into D1
cd ./D1

#Create 12 backup files .bak in D1 (using for loop)
for i in `seq 1 12`;
do
        #echo $I
        touch file$i.bak D1
done

#Create 12 backup files .txt~ in D1 (using set)
touch {a..l}.txt~ D1

#Create 12 files prefix # in D1 (using while loop)
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 12 ]; do
        touch \#$COUNTER.txt D1
        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done

#Once finished creating backup files in all 3 categories, do an ls -l
ls -l

#Invoke clean method here
./cleanUp.sh

#Do final ls - l
ls - l
```

This is clean.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Need to pass a directory in as argument
for i in "$@"
do
        echo file is: $I
done
```

I'm not sure how to pass in a directory as an argument and calling a method in another method is confusing. Thanks!

Comment: Well organized question. Keep posting. I think you want at the top of your `test.sh` something like `myDir=$1; if [ ! -d "$myDir" ] ; then echo "$myDir is not a directory, can't continue"; exit 1 ; fi`. And then use $myDir instead of $D1. Shell scripts always look at the "cmd-line", so to send $myDir to your `cleanup.sh`, you just do `./cleanup.sh "$myDir". Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is a nice start.
The touch commands can do without the parameter D1, your cleanup.sh call needs a parameter. The parameter ${PWD} is given by the shell, thats easy in this case.
(you can also give a parameter like /home/mina/test2/D1).

The script will look like

```
!/bin/bash
#Create new directory called D1
mkdir D1

#cd into D1
cd ./D1

#Create 12 backup files .bak in D1 (using for loop)
for i in `seq 1 12`;
do
        #echo $I
        touch file$i.bak
done

#Create 12 backup files .txt~ in D1 (using set)
touch {a..l}.txt~

#Create 12 files prefix # in D1 (using while loop)
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 12 ]; do
        touch \#$COUNTER.txt
        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done

#Once finished creating backup files in all 3 categories, do an ls -l
ls -l

#Invoke clean method here
./cleanUp.sh ${PWD}

#Do final ls - l
ls - l
```

Now the cleanup script.
First change `$I` into `$i`, the variable name is case sensitive.
With `for i in "$@"` you loop through the parameters (only the name of the dir),
and you would like to go through the diffferent filenames.
Try the following alternatives:

```
# Let Unix expand the * variable
for i in $1/*; do

# Use a subshell
for i in $(ls "$@"); do

# use a while-loop
ls $@ | while read i; do

# use find and while
find "$1" -type f | while read i; do

# use find and -exec
find "$1" -type f -exec echo File is {} \;

# use find and xargs
find "$1" -type f | xargs echo File is
```